# Fortran MPI Allgather for separate arrays

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I'm trying to distribute a large job with multiple arrays between different processes so that each process computes one given array. After this, I need all processes to end up having the same information. I'm trying to understand how to do this, and so far, I have been using `mpi_allgather`. However, the communication between processes doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
program main
use mpi
implicit none

integer           :: nproc,rank,ierr,i
integer,parameter :: n = 3
integer,parameter :: m = 2
double precision  :: x(n,m),y(n,m),z(m)

! Initializing MPI
call mpi_init(ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, rank,  ierr)
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, nproc, ierr)

! Initial values for x
x = 0.0
y = 1.0

! Do the following m times
do i = 1,m
    
    ! Distribute work in 2 processes
    if (rank == 0) then
        x(:,i) = x(:,i) + i
    end if

    if (rank == 1) then
        y(:,i) = y(:,i) * (i+1.0)
    end if

    ! MPI barrier
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world, ierr)

    ! Gathering (MPI), so all processes have the same data
    call mpi_allgather(mpi_in_place, n, mpi_double_precision, x(:,i), n, mpi_double_precision, mpi_comm_world, ierr)
    call mpi_allgather(mpi_in_place, n, mpi_double_precision, y(:,i), n, mpi_double_precision, mpi_comm_world, ierr)
    
    ! MPI barrier
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world, ierr)
    
    ! Using data from both processes
    z(i) = sum(x(:,i)) + sum(y(:,i))

    if (rank == 0)  then
        print *, i, z(i)
    end if

end do

! Finalizing MPI
call mpi_finalize(ierr)

end program main
```

With the barriers and the `mpi_allgather`, process 0 should print the same as if I was running it serially:

```
       1   9.00000000000000
       2   15.0000000000000
```

But it's giving me the wrong result. Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand it correctly your real problem is that what you want to do is not really an allgather. Allgather gathers together contributions from each *and every* process in the communicator and concatenates these contributions. Here only one process contributes. I think I would do it with mpi_allreduce, setting to zero the contributions from the processes that do nothing, but you could use mpi_allgather**V** with the length zero from processes that contribute nothing. Or if it is just for printing on proc 0  why not just send it? If this is correct please confirm, and I'll try and answer.

Comment: There is no inactive process, both of them are doing something. Process 0 is computing `x` and process 1 is computing `y`. I probably chose a bad example using `sum` for `z`, but what I wanted to show is that computing `z` requires having the full columns `i` of `x` and `y`. The printing part is just to not duplicate the output on the screen and is not the ultimate goal. I am using `print` just to check the MPI usage, but with the allgather both processes should be printing the same, no?

Comment: That is not what I am saying. mpi_allgather assumes you have part of x on process 0, another part on process 1, another on process 2, and so on. Here you have x entirely on process 0, a different array y on process 1, and so on. This is not what mpi_allgather deals with - it deals with the first case, concatenating all the separate parts held by different processes.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point. I'll check `mpi_allreduce` and `mpi_allgatherv` to see if one of them can do what I need.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I set `x(:,i)=0.0` when process 0 doesn't contribute (same thing with `y` and process 1), and then I do `call mpi_allreduce(mpi_in_place, x(:,i), n, mpi_double_precision, mpi_sum, mpi_comm_world, ierr)`, and likewise for `y`. This solution seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your `allgather` call you specify the send & receive data as `n` elements. That should be `1`: the amount of data from *each* process, not the sum total.
2. You're not using the `in_place` correctly: that assumes that each process already has its own data in place in the receive buffer, meaning that `x(myproc,i` needs to be set.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. About (1), I was trying to send `n` elements, as that is the dimension of each column of `x` and `y`. Should I do this element by element? About (2), I don't understand what needs to be set. How do I declare which process has the data and which others don't?

Comment: "I was trying to send n elements" per process?

Comment: "How do I declare which process has the data and which others don't?" If you do an allgather, then *every* process needs to have some of the data.

Comment: I mean, process 0 computes a column of `x` of dimension `n`, and then the idea is that it sends it to process 1. Same thing with process 1 computing columns of `y`. I guess I'll have to try something different to `mpi_allgather` then.

Comment: Sounds like you need a ring communication scheme. Look into `MPI_Sendrecv`.